# Vertically centering text in landscape mode tabular

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, landscape, vertical

I encounter a problem with vertically centering the content of my "big" table. I use tabular and I would like the text to be vertically and horizontally centered. Could you please help me with this problem ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%définition des packages
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, headsep=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}
\mtcselectlanguage{french}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Blabla  \protect}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & Image  \\
\hline\hline 
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{sova.png} \\
\hline 
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{sova.png} \\ 
\hline 
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{sova.png} \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the `C` column type?

Comment: It enables to horizontally center the text in the cells

Comment: But `array` already defines `wc{some length}` nowadays.

Comment: But that is not standard LaTeX; you would have to define it with `\newcolumntype`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibilities is `adjustbox` package, by its instruction `\valign=m`move image baseline to the (vertical) middle of image. For shorter code you also can use `\adjustimage` instead od `includegraphics` and define image options in `adjustboxset` instruction for all images in table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%définition des packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, 
            hmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm}, 
            headheight=1cm, headsep=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, amsmath, amssymb, cellspace, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=m, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Blabla  \protect}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & Image  \\
\hline\hline
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\
\hline
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\
\hline
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, in your preamble are many packages load many times with different options. Please, check preamble again and remove all duplicated packages and see, if you really need all those package.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the Image column with `m{3cm}`, the text entries will be aligned with the center of the images. To center the image column, I added  `>{\centering\arraybackslash}`. I redefine the `C` columns to do this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

%définition des packages
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, headsep=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}
\mtcselectlanguage{french}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Blabla  \protect}
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{2cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{2cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & Image  \\
\hline\hline 
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{example-image} \\
\hline 
bla & bla & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{example-image} \\ 
\hline 
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.99cm]{example-image} \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh it works perfectly !  Thank you so much for this ingenious tip, I will remember it.

Comment: Just one question, it seems that now, the text does not go to the line anymore, but overlapp the other cells. How could I do to have an automatically ?

Comment: If the text doesn't fit in the cells you should use `M{...}` instead of `C{...}`, or define `C` the same as `M` and the use `C` everywhere. I'll change the answer to do that.